# Meta generated variadic interface implementation

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, variadic-templates

I've got interface defined with a templated variadic list to have multiple methods matching each type:

```
template <typename T> struct IfaceElement { virtual void m(const T &) = 0; };
template <typename... Ts> struct Iface : IfaceElement<Ts>... {};
```

What I would like to achieve is to have an interface for a different number of `Event` object. Something like:

```
struct A {};
struct B {};
struct Handler : Iface<A, B> {
    void m(const A &) override { ... }
    void m(const B &) override { ... }
}
```

and it works fine.

However, I would also like to have a class that implements that interface and it is also meta-generated from variadic template.

I've thought that something like this should work:

```
template <typename T> struct IfaceElement { virtual void m(const T &) = 0; };
template <typename... Ts> struct Iface : IfaceElement<Ts>... {};

template <typename T> struct ImplElement : IfaceElement<T> {
    void m(const T &) override {}
};
template <typename... Ts> struct Impl : Iface<Ts...>, ImplElement<Ts>... {};

struct Z {};
struct X {};

Impl<Z, X> q;
```

But I've got a compiler error:

```
test.cpp:121:12: error: cannot declare variable 'q' to be of abstract type 'Impl<Z, X>'
  121 | Impl<Z, X> q;
      |            ^
test.cpp:116:34: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within 'Impl<Z, X>':
  116 | template <typename... Ts> struct Impl : Iface<Ts...>, ImplElement<Ts>... {};
      |                                  ^~~~
test.cpp:110:58: note:  'void IfaceElement<T>::m(const T&) [with T = X]'
  110 | template <typename T> struct IfaceElement { virtual void m(const T &) = 0; };
      |                                                          ^
test.cpp:110:58: note:  'void IfaceElement<T>::m(const T&) [with T = Z]'
```

It seems that my implementation from `ImplElement` is not matching `IfaceElement` pure method.

Any idea how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured this out, virtual inheritance is needed to match those interfaces.

Compiling code:

```
template <typename T> struct IfaceElement { virtual void m(const T &) = 0; };
template <typename... Ts> struct Iface : virtual IfaceElement<Ts>... {};

template <typename T> struct ImplElement : virtual IfaceElement<T> {
    void m(const T &) override {}
};
template <typename... Ts> struct Impl : Iface<Ts...>, ImplElement<Ts>... {};

struct Z {};
struct X {};

Impl<Z, X> q;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are inheriting from `IfaceElement` 2 times. Once through `ImplElement` and once through `Iface`.

That means

```
template <typename... Ts> struct Impl : Iface<Ts...>, ImplElement<Ts>... {};
```

will have two identical `IfaceElement`s for each `Ts`.

You can sovel it by using virtual inheritance, but why do you need to inherit twice from the same base?

```
template <typename... Ts> struct Impl : ImplElement<Ts>... {};
```

Will also work and inherits from `IfaceElement` only once per `Ts`.

Comment: I think I need to inherit from Iface to be able to pass Impl reference to functions that needs a reference to Iface.